# Regular expression to not match "www"

Tags: regex

I guess I'm getting really weak in logic.

I need to write a regular expression which matches everything except `www`. It should match `wwwd`, `abcd` and everything else, just *not* `www`. (Oh God, please, it shouldn't be very easy).

I'm using Ruby language's implementation of regular expression.

UPDATE: I need to use regular expression and not just `text != 'www'` because it is the way API is designed. It expects a *pattern* as argument and not the *result*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why regex? Isn't `text != "www"` enough?

Here it is nonetheless (uses [look-ahead](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5108)): `^(?!www$).*`

Comment: This match empty string on non "www" string, not the whole word.

Answer (score 4):

This is a plain vanilla regex. There are fancier things you can do with negative assertions in certain dialects.

```
^(.|..|[^w]..|.[^w].|..[^w]|.....*)$
```

In English:

You want something that's exactly one character, exactly two characters, exactly three characters where at least one of those 3 is not a w, or more than 3 characters long.

Comment: @soulmerge: the last period isn't superfluous (assuming you're saying it shouldn't be five periods). It's four periods (....) plus zero or more additional characters (.*) for a total of five periods. It could also be specified as "....+".

Comment: Ah, I thought it *was* a plus at the end. I guess seeing 5 periods brought up the confusion (I was expecting *4* or more letters).

Answer (score 1):

Same general idea as Laurence Gonsalves(*), but it seems to me one could say `^.$|^..$|^....+$|.*[^w].*`  That is, 1 or 2 or more than 3 characters between start and end, or any number containing a non-w.

(*) I really meant this to be a comment on his answer, but accidentally posted it as my own answer.  I guess I'll just leave it here.

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach

```
^.{0,2}([^w].*|.{4,})?$
```